# Do I need to learn c# beforestarting to work with asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Just wondering if I needed to know c# before I can start working with asp.net,

can I learn them together?

what is a good starting point like a book or online tutorials.

thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Personally* I'd start by learning C# without ASP.NET, preferrably via console applications. That way you can get to grips with the language and the core types (collections, I/O, text, primitives etc) without being hampered by all the extra stuff ASP.NET throws in your way.

There are various oddities in any "peripheral" technology (ASP.NET, WCF, WPF, WinForms etc) that it can be very confusing if you don't know the core stuff well: if something goes wrong, you can easily end up not having the faintest idea where to start finding the problem. Is it a misunderstanding about the language? The collections? The way that ASP.NET events are autowired? I'm sure you see what I mean :)

[C# 3.0 in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527578) is a good book in terms of covering the language and the core framework. Then get a good ASP.NET book separately.

Comment: I agree with Jon.  Start simpler ASP.NET gets complicated quickly because it is stateless.  Windows forms is an much easier place to start, with a Console being the best way.

Comment: Of course he should follow up his reading with "C# in Depth" ;)

Comment: @Jonathan: You might very well think that. I couldn't possibly comment.

Comment: Oddities in ASP.Net?  Say it ain't so ;)

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET is a web framework - in other words it is simply a set of libraries that make creating websites easier by abstracting away all the tedious details.  In order to write code to harness this framework you will need to use one of Microsoft's .NET languages (C#, VB.NET, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

you can also use vb.net (visual basic). Might be beneficial if you are already familiar with it

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start learning asp.net before C#. But you'll really benefit from doing both together.

http://www.learnvisualstudio.net has loads of great video-tutorials (ASP.NET, VB.NET and C#).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can learn them both at the same time, it is often easier to start if you know C# or VB beforehand, but not a requirement at all to be successful.

There are many places to start, but 4GuysFromRolla.com is a great tutorial site.  Otherwise, any of the beginning ASP.NET books would be a good starting point from a book.

Answer (score 0):

C# in my opinion is the easiest of the languages supported by the Dot Net framework. I would suggest starting there.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET leverages the multi-language capabilities of the .NET Common Language Runtime, allowing web pages to be coded in VB.NET, C#, J#, Delphi.NET, Chrome etc. This means you don't have to learn C# to use it and, even if you don't know any of those languages, you may find it easier to start with a more human readable one such as VB.NET.

In any case, I recommend the following tutorials if you do plan on learning C#:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28VS.71%29.aspx