# Is it necessary to learn C# before learning ASP.net for person from java background?

Tags: asp.net

I'm going to learn asp.net by taking a institute coaching. I have background of java programming but no idea about .NET development. My question is do i need to learn C# first before learning ASP.NET ?

There is [similar question like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306460/do-i-need-to-learn-c-beforestarting-to-work-with-asp-net) but as i'm from java background i would like to know better suggestion than generalize one in similar questions posted earlier.

What if your suggestion about this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not learning C#, or VB.Net, or any language that matter, you're leaning the **Framework**.  The big difference is you're leaning the classes, the life cycle (whether it be MVC or WebForms or whatever).  The language isn't all that different from java in most areas in terms of syntax, it's the classes and what's in the framework that's the difference.

I'd say no, you don't need to learn C#, coming from java the language will be the easiest part, you'll learn the nuances as you go along.  Learning what's in the framework itself, regardless of language, that's what will take a bit of time, not that's it difficult, there's just lots available.  You'll never learn it all, and you don't need to, you learn what you need as you go along.

As a side note, there are projects out there that exist in both java and .net, for example [hibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/) and [nHibernate](http://nhforge.org/), you could dig through these to see a decent comparison of what's available in both worlds and how some things translate across.  I'm sure there are plenty more, but can't think of any big ones at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Java background or not, Jon Skeet answered your question on the other thread. ASP.NET is a framework built on .NET and not a programming language in itself, so you'll need to learn a .NET language in order to develop ASP.NET applications.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to need to know a whole lot, the basics are the same. Syntax is similar.

I would recommend you take some time to familiarise yourself with it nonetheless not so much from a language point of view, but to gain experience with the .net framework. It's analagous to the various java sdk libraries etc, and as I'm sure you can appreciate, an understanding of the framework with which you are working is invaluable when building applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn them both at the same time; an ASP.NET page has a markup page for HTML/server controls and a code-behind for your code.  With your Java background, you'll understand the syntax (with some varying syntax to learn).  So in my opinion, you don't need to have a full knowledge of C#, just some basic syntaxes.  Most examples show ASP.NET and C# or VB code together, so you can learn both at once.